# JS OOP. Inheritance and apply() function. Why it doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, apply, function-constructor

I have such example.

```
function Bar() {
    this.barVal = "BarValue";
}

function Foo() {
    this.fooVal = "FooValue";
    Bar.apply(this, arguments);   // here I use apply() to get access everything in Bar from Foo;
}
var barObj = new Bar;
var fooObj = new Foo;

alert(fooObj.barVal);     // the output is `BarValue`
```

Now I want the same way get access to everything in Foo from Bar. I modify my code:

```
function Bar() {
    this.barVal = "BarValue";
    Foo.apply(this, arguments);   // I add the same line of code, just change names
}

function Foo() {
    this.fooVal = "FooValue";
    Bar.apply(this, arguments);   // and also leave it here because I want previous functionality too
}
var barObj = new Bar;
var fooObj = new Foo;

alert(fooObj.barVal);     
alert(barObj.fooVal);     // there is no any output for both
```

But there is no any output. I fact some mistake occurs. When I hide `Foo.apply(this, arguments);` under the comment, the call `alert(fooObj.barVal);` works again. When I check it like this:

```
function Bar() {
    this.barVal = "BarValue";
    try {
        Foo.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

it even stops browser work (I use Chrome so whole blaсk screen with pixel folder on it appears). And in alert-window it writes `RangeError: undefined`

BUT as I have alert calls in this sequence

```
alert(fooObj.barVal);     
alert(barObj.fooVal);
```

the second alert shows exactly what I'm waiting for from it - it shows `BarValue`.

Why apply() doesn't work when I duplicate it in Bar? Is it possible somehow to make such kind of gates between two functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apply` calls the function, using whatever `this` you specify.

Think about that for a second.  If `Foo` calls `Bar`, and `Bar` calls `Foo`, then you end up with infinite recursion.  You need some kind of way to say "don't call `Foo` again".  Or at the very least, Foo needs to be able to see "hey, i've already been called once; don't do anything this time".

Truth be told, though, the fact that you need to do any of that smells.  You generally don't want circular dependencies like that; if the two thingies are so intertwined that they need each other's functionality in order to work, it sounds like you might be able to split off the intertwined stuff into a separate type and use both `Foo` and `Bar` from there, or have both inherit from it, or something.  But i'd need to see more of the design in order to say anything specific about any of that.